# sqlite3 Select with two parameters

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, lambda

So I have a table with two attributes, Parent and Child. They refer to nodes and the table is created. I must use a lambda function that returns the parent only if the two parameters given share the same parent. For example lets say I have the (parent, child) pairs (a, b) and (a,e). B and E are the two input parameters so since they share a parent, func(b,e) will return 'a'.

```
import sqlite3

dog = sqlite3.connect("example1.db")
c = dog.cursor()
r = [('c','a'),('a','b'), ('a','e'),('c','d'),
          ('c','f'),('f','g'), ('f','h'),('h','j'),
          ('h','i')]

c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS G')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE G (Parent text, Child)''')

c.executemany('INSERT INTO G VALUES (?,?)', r)

dog.commit()


q = lambda x,y: 'SELECT G.Parent FROM G WHERE G.Child == "e"'


print(c.execute(q('b','e')).fetchone())
print(c.execute(q('h','g')).fetchone())
print(c.execute(q('e','a')).fetchone())

dog.close()
```

right now I have that which only returns the parent of 'e' cause im lost.

Answer (score 0):

A query that should satisfy your requirement of finding the common parent(s) is:

```
   q = """select a.parent 
   from 
       (select parent from g where child = ?) a
   inner join 
       (select parent from g where child = ?) b
   on a.parent = b.parent"""

   print(c.execute(q, ('b', 'e')).fetchall())
```

Since you're specifying you need to use a lambda function, I'm guessing that this is probably some type of homework assignment.  I don't know what you or your instructor's limitations on the lambda are, but I'd probably write a function that returns a set of parents and then use the lambda to return the intersection.  Pseudo-code since this is probably homework:

```
def getParents:
    return set( parents of child )

q = lambda x,y: getParents(x).intersection(getParents(y))

print q('b','e')
```